# Two divs in same row when click on one expand both tailwind css Django alpine js

Tags: django, tailwind-css, alpine.js

[image before opening div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugPvu.png)

[image after clicking on div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmc9q.png)

[CODE SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6M5e.png)

PARENT

```
   <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-x-4 mt-8">
    
</div>
```

CHILD

```
<div x-init x-data="{expanded: false}" :class="expanded ? 'h-full' : 'h-12'" class="w-full md:w-48/100 flex flex-col">
<div @click="expanded = !expanded" class="flex items-center px-10 py-4 border-b bg-white rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
    <div class="font-bold font-lato text-xsm bg-white">{{ value.question }}</div>
    <div class="ml-auto p-2">
        <svg width="8" height="6" viewBox="0 0 8 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M7.77083 0.937549C7.68535 0.850049 7.57545 0.812549 7.46555 0.812549C7.35565 0.812549 7.23354 0.862549 7.16027 0.937549L4.03424 4.11255L0.932622 0.937549C0.847145 0.850049 0.725034 0.800049 0.615134 0.800049C0.505234 0.800049 0.383123 0.850049 0.309857 0.925049C0.138902 1.10005 0.138902 1.38755 0.309857 1.56255L3.71675 5.06255C3.8877 5.23755 4.16856 5.23755 4.33951 5.06255L7.75862 1.57505C7.94178 1.40005 7.94178 1.11255 7.77083 0.937549Z"
                  fill="#080F33">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div x-show="expanded" class="px-10 py-4 text-left font-lato bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 flex-1">
    {{ value.answer|richtext }}
</div>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Looking at the second image, it already works as expected, right?

Comment: the other one should not expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking at your code snippet. Your right option isn't expanding. It may look like it is, because your current HTML/CSS is expanding the parent container. If you want 2 separate columns, you will need to make it as such in your HTML/CSS:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
      .md-w-48\/100 {
        width: 48%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap w-full">
      <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap w-full mt-8 px-6 xl:px-0">
        <h2 class="text-4xl font-mont font-bold md:text-left text-center">Casino &amp; Gambling FAQs</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="max-w-7xl mt-8 px-6 xl:px-0 w-1/2 inline-block">
        <div class="flex flex-col flex-wrap justify-between w-full">
          <div class="flex flex-wrap flex-row justify-between mt-8 w-full">
            <div x-init="" x-data="{expanded: false}" :class="expanded ? 'h-full' : 'h-12'" class="w-full flex flex-wrap flex-col h-12">
              <div @click="expanded = !expanded" class="flex items-center px-10 py-4 border-b bg-white rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
                <div class="font-bold font-lato text-xsm bg-white">question</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2">
                  <svg width="8" height="6" viewBox="0 0 8 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M7.77083 0.937549C7.68535 0.850049 7.57545 0.812549 7.46555 0.812549C7.35565 0.812549 7.23354 0.862549 7.16027 0.937549L4.03424 4.11255L0.932622 0.937549C0.847145 0.850049 0.725034 0.800049 0.615134 0.800049C0.505234 0.800049 0.383123 0.850049 0.309857 0.925049C0.138902 1.10005 0.138902 1.38755 0.309857 1.56255L3.71675 5.06255C3.8877 5.23755 4.16856 5.23755 4.33951 5.06255L7.75862 1.57505C7.94178 1.40005 7.94178 1.11255 7.77083 0.937549Z" fill="#080F33">
                    </path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div x-show="expanded" class="px-10 py-4 text-left font-lato bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 flex-1" style="display: none;">
                'just a bunch of text'
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-wrap flex-row justify-between mt-8 w-full">
            <div x-init="" x-data="{expanded: false}" :class="expanded ? 'h-full' : 'h-12'" class="w-full flex flex-wrap flex-col h-12">
              <div @click="expanded = !expanded" class="flex items-center px-10 py-4 border-b bg-white rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
                <div class="font-bold font-lato text-xsm bg-white">question</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2">
                  <svg width="8" height="6" viewBox="0 0 8 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M7.77083 0.937549C7.68535 0.850049 7.57545 0.812549 7.46555 0.812549C7.35565 0.812549 7.23354 0.862549 7.16027 0.937549L4.03424 4.11255L0.932622 0.937549C0.847145 0.850049 0.725034 0.800049 0.615134 0.800049C0.505234 0.800049 0.383123 0.850049 0.309857 0.925049C0.138902 1.10005 0.138902 1.38755 0.309857 1.56255L3.71675 5.06255C3.8877 5.23755 4.16856 5.23755 4.33951 5.06255L7.75862 1.57505C7.94178 1.40005 7.94178 1.11255 7.77083 0.937549Z" fill="#080F33">
                    </path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div x-show="expanded" class="px-10 py-4 text-left font-lato bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 flex-1" style="display: none;">
                'just a bunch of text'
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="max-w-7xl mt-8 px-6 xl:px-0 w-1/2 inline-block">
        <div class="flex flex-col flex-wrap justify-between w-full">
          <div class="flex flex-wrap flex-row justify-between mt-8 w-full">
            <div x-init="" x-data="{expanded: false}" :class="expanded ? 'h-full' : 'h-12'" class="w-full flex flex-wrap flex-col h-12">
              <div @click="expanded = !expanded" class="flex items-center px-10 py-4 border-b bg-white rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
                <div class="font-bold font-lato text-xsm bg-white">question</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2">
                  <svg width="8" height="6" viewBox="0 0 8 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M7.77083 0.937549C7.68535 0.850049 7.57545 0.812549 7.46555 0.812549C7.35565 0.812549 7.23354 0.862549 7.16027 0.937549L4.03424 4.11255L0.932622 0.937549C0.847145 0.850049 0.725034 0.800049 0.615134 0.800049C0.505234 0.800049 0.383123 0.850049 0.309857 0.925049C0.138902 1.10005 0.138902 1.38755 0.309857 1.56255L3.71675 5.06255C3.8877 5.23755 4.16856 5.23755 4.33951 5.06255L7.75862 1.57505C7.94178 1.40005 7.94178 1.11255 7.77083 0.937549Z" fill="#080F33">
                    </path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div x-show="expanded" class="px-10 py-4 text-left font-lato bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 flex-1" style="display: none;">
                'just a bunch of text'
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-wrap flex-row justify-between mt-8 w-full">
            <div x-init="" x-data="{expanded: false}" :class="expanded ? 'h-full' : 'h-12'" class="w-full flex flex-wrap flex-col h-12">
              <div @click="expanded = !expanded" class="flex items-center px-10 py-4 border-b bg-white rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
                <div class="font-bold font-lato text-xsm bg-white">question</div>
                <div class="ml-auto p-2">
                  <svg width="8" height="6" viewBox="0 0 8 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M7.77083 0.937549C7.68535 0.850049 7.57545 0.812549 7.46555 0.812549C7.35565 0.812549 7.23354 0.862549 7.16027 0.937549L4.03424 4.11255L0.932622 0.937549C0.847145 0.850049 0.725034 0.800049 0.615134 0.800049C0.505234 0.800049 0.383123 0.850049 0.309857 0.925049C0.138902 1.10005 0.138902 1.38755 0.309857 1.56255L3.71675 5.06255C3.8877 5.23755 4.16856 5.23755 4.33951 5.06255L7.75862 1.57505C7.94178 1.40005 7.94178 1.11255 7.77083 0.937549Z" fill="#080F33">
                    </path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div x-show="expanded" class="px-10 py-4 text-left font-lato bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 flex-1" style="display: none;">
                'just a bunch of text'
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've split your columns in to 2 different `inline-block` elements. This way, it is not seen as one parent, and expanding a child won't expand the container on the other side.